# is the frame after executing setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded always get accurate view's frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, runloop

My understanding is, after execute `setNeedsLayout` will mark the view as "dirty" so that in the next rendering cycle, the view will be be re-layout. `layoutIfNeeded` will force to trigger re-layout immediately if the view is marked as "dirty".

However, even `layoutIfNeeded` immediately start to layout, it does not mean that the code after `layoutIfNeeded` will be waiting until it finishes. The render part is an async operation, it will be handled by core graphic through runloop.

```
myView.setNeedsLayout()
myView.layoutIfneeded()
print(myView.frame)
```

My point is, the printing of frame above may not always get correct frame, since the render operation is an async task, am I right?

Some context:

1. myView is render finished.
2. one of its subview's height constraint get changed due to some async data task.
3. execute above setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeed like mentioned above.

Comment: Neither of those affect the view's frame. They lead to `layoutSubviews` being called. While `myView.frame` is not going to change, the frame of its subviews might change.

Comment: @HangarRash but the frame will be affect if any subview's constraint changes right?

Comment: If your goal is to ensure constraints get updated, and possibly result in the size of `myView` changing, then you probably want to use `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` after making any change related to constraints.

Comment: the goal is to get accurate frame after constraint is updated.

Comment: May I ask why you need the frame? If you are using constraints, knowing the frame isn't normally needed.

Comment: Good question. You can assume this is an old project has highly coupled logic to update tableHeaderView using frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am I right

Yes. If you want the frame right now, either flush the current transaction or (perhaps better) allow a cycle by doing a zero-delay `asyncAfter`. See [How to, simply, wait for any layout in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420178/how-to-simply-wait-for-any-layout-in-ios) (and probably I should just be closing this question as a dupe of that one).

I should mention that an even better way is just to implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews`. That way, you arrive into the layout cycle at exactly the right moment to obtain any desired frame info.

Comment: oh, the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0)` will wait till current runloop finish, even delay is 0?